# Cannot properly configure a gateway on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, iptables, router, gateway

I'm trying to make a gateway using Ubuntu 16.04, my server has the following nics:

```
enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:c5:f6:c0:36
          inet addr:192.168.0.101  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:c5ff:fef6:c036/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5118 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3065 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:7474529 (7.4 MB)  TX bytes:254689 (254.6 KB)
          Interrupt:16

enp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:08:54:31:8f:79
          inet addr:172.24.3.19  Bcast:172.24.3.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::208:54ff:fe31:8f79/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7573 errors:0 dropped:334 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2756 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:756664 (756.6 KB)  TX bytes:881724 (881.7 KB)
```

enp4s0 is WAN nic, connected to Internet.
enp6s0 is LAN nic.

I configured them as it is on `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
allow-hotplug enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug enp6s0
iface enp6s0 inet static
address 172.24.3.19
netmask 255.255.252.0
gateway 172.24.0.1
dns-nameservers 172.24.3.1
```

enp4s0 received ip as follows, extracted from `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.enp4s0.leases`:

```
lease {
  interface "enp4s0";
  fixed-address 192.168.0.101;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.168.0.1;
  option dhcp-lease-time 7200;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.1,8.8.8.8;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.0.1;
  renew 5 2018/06/08 16:03:17;
  rebind 5 2018/06/08 16:59:19;
  expire 5 2018/06/08 17:14:19;
}
```

Following [Nairabytes.net](http://www.nairabytes.net/81-linux/418-how-to-set-up-a-nat-router-on-ubuntu-server-16-04), I applied some iptables rules as followed:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp4s0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp4s0 -o enp6s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp6s0 -o enp4s0 -j ACCEPT
```

So iptables rules became as followed:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

But what I cannot understand is why just one of two nics works properly. While this server can talk to LAN by enp6s0, it cannot connect to internet.

So I apply this route to it:

```
sudo /sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.0.1 enp4s0
```

And the thing goes reverted! Now the server can connect to internet, but becomes unaccessible to LAN.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You did step 3, right? Also, step 1 looks incorrect, because a gateway should not be specified for enp0s8.

Comment: I agree, @DougSmythies, but I couldn't make server connect to internet except by this command. Talking about gateway, I post `/etc/network/interfaces` info to my question to clarify. I believe DHCP heritage settings aren't bringing gateway info.

Comment: It might help if we could see the last entry in your `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.enp4s0.leases` file. The gateway, if it is supplied, would be called `option routers`. My main gateway/router is the same as what you are trying to do.

Comment: OK @DougSmythies, I added last entry at my question info

Comment: It all looks correct. Take out the `gateway` and `dns-nameservers` lines from your enp6s0 area of your `interfaces` file.

Comment: For this to work properly the gateway for your 172.24.0.0 sub-net needs to be 172.24.3.19.

Comment: @DougSmythies, changing 172.24.0.0 to 172.24.3.19 as gw at enp6s0 didn't work, because nobody at lan couldn't ping or connect to it. My Lan has several subnets (172.24.4.0/23 - 172.24.6.0/23 - 172.24.32.0/24, etc). This gateway must be visible to whole the LAN.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78663/discussion-between-doug-smythies-and-redbob).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo /sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.0.1 enp4s0
```

This sets a route for *everything* to 192.168.0.1.

You probably want to add default gateway, which means anything not matching any more specific routes goes here. This can be done with the following command:

```
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp4s0
```

In addition, you will need a route for 172.24.0.0/16 on the other NIC:

```
sudo ip route add -net 172.24.0.0/16 via 172.24.3.1 dev enp6s0
```

This will add a route to your local 172.240.0/16-network, enabling you to reach this network. As this is a more specific route, it is picked over default for packets going to 172.24.0.0.

Comment: these commands you suggested didn't worked, so I get successfully type that instead: `sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1 enp4s0` and `sudo ip route add 172.24.0.0/16 via 172.24.0.1 dev enp6s0` because our gw is 0.1, not 3.1